# Получить значение атрибута в массиве

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
<div class="card" v-for="api in apis">
  <p>{{ api.child_name }}</p>
  <input class="form-control" id="child_name" type="text" name="name" v-model="name" ref="click">
  <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" @click="get">Получить</button>
</div>

<script>
   methods: {
     get(){
       alert(this.$refs.click.id);
     },
   }
</script>
```

Есть некий массив и поле ввода, можно ли как то в цикле получить значение id у input  ?
Так же возможно полей ввода будет несколько
Вне массива данный код прекрасно работает...

Comment: для чего вам получать id ?

Comment: Будет более 10 input и каждый id будет отправлять в базу изменения, по этому либо нужно какой нибудь отличительный идентификатор, либо какое нибудь уникальное значение для каждого input

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете привязать v-model к свойству элемента

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    items: [
     {name: 'First', value: ''},
      {name: 'Second', value: ''},
      {name: 'Third', value: ''},
    ],
    input: [],
  },
  methods: {
   submit(){
     console.log(this.items);
    },
  }
})
```

```css
#app{
  padding: 0 0 80px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <div v-for="(item, index) in items">
        <div>{{item.name}}</div>
        <input v-model="item.value" :key="index">
    </div>
    <button v-on:click="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```